# Insert several records with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Friends my registration function in codeigniter have to calculate the amount of parcels that intend to register. And with that insert multiple records in the table with the dates of the installments. So step the number of the number of installments and the starting date of the installments by url . I took a var_dump but not returning anything.

```
   public function cadastrar($nParcelas = null, $dataPrimeiraParcela = null){ esta_logado();
    $nParcelas = $this->input->post('localidade');
    $dt_parcelas = $this->input->post('datainicial'); $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Este %s já está cadastrado no sistema'); $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'O campo %s está diferente do campo %s'); $this->form_validation->set_rules('aquiller', 'AQUILLER', 'trim|required|ucwords'); $this->form_validation->set_rules('localidad', 'NUMERO PARCELAS', 'trim|required'); $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicial', 'FECHA DE ENTRADA', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE):
        if($dataPrimeiraParcela && $nParcelas != null){
            $dataPrimeiraParcela = explode( "/",$this->input->post('datainicial'));
            $dia = $dataPrimeiraParcela[0];
            $mes = $dataPrimeiraParcela[1];
            $ano = $dataPrimeiraParcela[2];
        } else {
            $dia = date("d");
            $mes = date("m");
            $ano = date("Y");
        }
    for($x = 1; $x <= $nParcelas; $x++){
        $dt_parcelas[$x] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0,$mes,$dia,$ano)));
        }
        var_dump($nParcelas);
    foreach ($dt_parcelas as $vencimento)
        {
            $dados = array(
                'id_aquiler_parcelas' => $this->input->post('aquiler'),
                'venc_parcelas' => $vencimento
            ); $this->sindico->base($dados);
        } endif; set_tema('titulo', 'Cadastro de Parcelas a Pagar'); set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('parcelas', 'cadastrar')); load_template(); }
```

Comment: any error , notices

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/parcelas.php

Comment: form validation is ok?

Comment: Yes. From validation is ok. No foreach.

Comment: ucwords as a validation rule i not found in codeigniter validation rules docs

Comment: since $dt_parcelas  is empty array that is why it gives invalid suppied for foreach rule, can  dt_parcelas  have empty results

Answer (score 1):

**use this:**

```
       function cadastrar($nParcelas = NULL, $dataPrimeiraParcela = NULL){ 
          esta_logado();
          $nParcelas = $this->input->post('localidade');
          $dt_parcelas = $this->input->post('datainicial'); 
          $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Este %s já está cadastrado no sistema'); 
          $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'O campo %s está diferente do campo %s'); 
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('aquiller', 'AQUILLER', 'trim|required|ucwords'); 
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('localidad', 'NUMERO PARCELAS', 'trim|required'); 
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicial', 'FECHA DE ENTRADA', 'trim|required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE):
              if(!empty($dataPrimeiraParcela) && !empty($nParcelas)){
                  $dataPrimeiraParcela = explode( "/",$this->input->post('datainicial'));
                  $dia = $dataPrimeiraParcela[0];
                  $mes = $dataPrimeiraParcela[1];
                  $ano = $dataPrimeiraParcela[2];
              } else {
                  $dia = date("d");
                  $mes = date("m");
                  $ano = date("Y");
             }
        for($x = 1; $x <= $nParcelas; $x++){
            $dt_parcelas[$x] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0,$mes,$dia,$ano)));
         }
         //var_dump($nParcelas);
         if(!empty($dt_parcelas)) {
              foreach ($dt_parcelas as $vencimento)
              {
                  $dados = array(
                'id_aquiler_parcelas' => $this->input->post('aquiler'),
                'venc_parcelas' => $vencimento
               ); 

         $this->sindico->base($dados);
        }
   }
     endif; set_tema('titulo', 'Cadastro de Parcelas a Pagar'); set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('parcelas', 'cadastrar')); load_template(); }
```

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/parcelas.php

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($nParcelas)

Comment: friend I took $nParcelas . and enter a fixed number . however the error continues. as my goal is to generate plots , I'm using foreach , creating the array data. so my doubt is ? Can I create the array controller?

Comment: and what about the output of  $dt_parcelas

Comment: For what purpose   esta_logado();is at the top of  method

Comment: estalogado is a funçãode session and is working well .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117643/discussion-between-ramon-chaves-and-pradeep).